# How to do successfull transaction on payUMoney??My transaction is Failed

Tags: c#

hi i m creating PayUMoney Payment Gateway and i m sending parametrs to c# code..then test site is open..after entring test card no,CVV,test Name my transaction process start but after that my transaction is failed..i dont know how it is?? please help me to solve my problem.

```
enter code here

 public string Generatehash512(string text)  //this is Hash generate method
{

    byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

        UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] hashValue;
        SHA512Managed hashString = new SHA512Managed();
        string hex = "";
        hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message);
        foreach (byte x in hashValue)
        {
            hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
        }
        return hex;
```

}

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hash1))   //all parameter that i sent.
    {
        hash.Value = hash1; 
        txnid.Value = txnid1;

        System.Collections.Hashtable data = new 
         System.Collections.Hashtable(); // adding values in gash table for data post
        data.Add("hash", hash.Value);
        data.Add("key", key.Value);
        data.Add("txnid", txnid.Value);

             string AmountForm = 
          Convert.ToDecimal(amount.Text.Trim()).ToString("g29");// eliminating trailing zeros

            amount.Text = AmountForm;
            data.Add("amount", amount.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("firstname", firstname.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("email", email.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("phone", phone.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("productinfo", productinfo.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("surl", surl.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("furl", furl.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("lastname", lastname.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("curl", curl.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("address1", address1.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("address2", address2.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("city", city.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("state", state.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("country", country.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("zipcode", zipcode.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("udf1", udf1.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("udf2", udf2.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("udf3", udf3.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("udf4", udf4.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("udf5", udf5.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("pg", pg.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("service_provider", service_provider.Text.Trim());
            data.Add("abc", hash_string);

            string strForm = PreparePOSTForm(action1, data);
        Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm));

    }
```

Comment: you need to call PayUMoney developer support.

Comment: Check their documentation at https://www.payumoney.com/dev-guide/ It has sample requests and responses.

Comment: ok @ Vishal And @john

Comment: hey vishal and John Key and salt are provide by PayU side :-https://www.payumoney.com/dev-guide/development/general.html.....please open this URL and check key and salt...can i Use this??

Comment: Hey John, My request hash is right and aslo match the response hash...but my Resuest.form["Status"]  is Failure..why this??

Comment: @pankaj what API are you testing? Post the response you're getting.

Comment: eCwWELxi|failure|||||||||||hingepankaj92@gmail.com|pankaj|its casual shirt|1.00|ccd5b50d44b46d4f8707|gtKFFx,...........this is my response Hash

Comment: status is "Failure" in display in response

Comment: hey john..my payumoney testing is done..successfully run on test server...use proper key and salt and card name,card number ,cvv that is available on payumoney.com